# How Do I Remote Desktop to a VMWare Windows 10 VM, not the base machine?

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, vmware-workstation

I have a PC running Windows 10. On that PC I have VMWare hosting a Windows 10 VM. I can run the VM without issue from the local machine. The VM has a typical Windows PC Name, different from the base machine.
When I try to make a Remote Desktop connection from a different PC to the VM using the VM PC Name, it connects to the base machine. I can see the VM running on the base machine and control it.
I need to be able to run several VM's on this base machine and then use RDP to run remote desktop sessions on the VM's.
Other configuration info:

- The VM Network is configured as NAT and I have followed the instructions here
  (https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1018809)
- If I change to Bridged for the Network then I can ping my other PC from the VM if I set up a
  fixed IP address - nothing if I try DHCP but that may be due to company network constraints.
- In Bridged mode, I can't ping back to the VM from my other PC. (Edit: fixed, this was just Network Discovery and Firewall settings)
  I need this system running on Windows 10 as our IT department doesn't want to support my application (even though they agree to it being used) which means I can't go to a Windows Server option. Also, the VM's need to be Windows 10 for application compatibility.
- All the equipment under test is in the same LAN subnet and on a single, dumb switch.
  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Launch the menu item VM > Settings.
- Search the start menu for command prompt from within the virtual machine. Enter ipconfig in the prompt and search for a value following the IPv4 Address. Record this address for later use.
- Now select the menu item Edit > Virtual Network Editor.
- Select the NAT network type and then choose NAT Settings.
- From this new prompt, click Add to include a new port forwarder.
- Enter the following information: **Host Port**: 9997, **Type**: TCP, **Virtual machine IP address**: Enter the IP you recorded in Step 2.
  note: This port number is 3389 by default, Save any open prompts so the configuration changes can take place.
- The final step is to enable RDP connections from within the operating system itself.

Comment: As I said, I followed these steps at the linked website but without success.